# C++ Creating a Weighted Graph?

Tags: c++, graph

How do I create a C++ weighted Graph where each vertex in the graph has a weight (some integer value)?

You can download my graph project [here](http://rapidshare.com/files/317273914/Graphs.rar.html) (RapidShare):

Here is the function to create a graph from graph data stored in a text file:

```
void GraphType::createGraph()
{
    ifstream infile;
    char fileName[50];

    int index;
    int vertex;
    int adjacentVertex;

    if(gSize != 0)
        clearGraph();

    cout << "Enter input file name: ";
    cin >> fileName;
    cout << endl;

    infile.open(fileName);

    if(!infile)
    {
            cout << "Cannot open input file." << endl;
            return;
    }

    infile >> gSize;

    graph = new UnorderedLinkList[gSize];

    for(index = 0; index < gSize; index++)
    {
            infile >> vertex;
            infile >> adjacentVertex;

            while(adjacentVertex != -999)
            {
                graph[ vertex ].insertLast(adjacentVertex);
                infile >> adjacentVertex;
            }
    }
    infile.close();
}
```

And here is the Graph data (number of vertices = 10, vertex 0 to 9 and adjacent vertices) input from text file "Network2.txt":

> 10
>
> 0 1 2 9 -999
>
> 1 0 2 -999
>
> 2 0 1 9 8 3 -999
>
> 3 2 8 5 -999
>
> 4 3 8 6 5 -999
>
> 5 4 6 7 -999
>
> 6 4 7 8 -999
>
> 7 8 6 5 -999
>
> 8 9 2 3 4 6 7 -999
>
> 9 0 2 8 -999

My question is, how do i assign a unique value or weight to vertices 0 to 9? Any assistance will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't revert and leave the markup broken.

Comment: Ok, thanks gf, I'll make note of that

Answer (score 5):

The [*Boost Graph Library*](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/graph/doc/table_of_contents.html) (BGL) offers type [`MutablePropertyGraph`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/graph/doc/MutablePropertyGraph.html), within which each edge and vertex can store a weight as a property. See the [example here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/graph/doc/graph_concepts.html), which builds up a directed graph with weighted edges.

Comment: Thanks very much Seh for reminding me that I need to start learning and using the Boost Library. I am downloading it as I write this and can't wait to try out the MutablePropertyGraph.

Unfortunately, for this class exercise, I have to create the graph and all of its functions from scratch! But thanks for the very useful link!

Answer (score 4):

In your adjacency list, instead of having it just store the indexes of the adjacent node, have it store a struct that contains the indexes of the adjacent node, and a value for the edge connecting those nodes.

Comment: Thank you Nali4Freedom for replying.

Your answer sounds very interesting. However, after some thought, I am still not sure how to implement your it into my project. Tell me if I am far off from your solution with this code below:



struct Vertex
{
       int numVertices;
       int vertex;
       int adjacentVertices[];
       int weight;
       
};

int main()
{
    Vertex v0;
    
    v0.vertex = 0;
    v0.adjacentVertices[0] = 1;
    v0.adjacentVertices[1] = 2;
    v0.adjacentVertices[2] = 9;
    v0.weight = 19;
    
    Vertex v1;
    //...
 system ("pause");   
}

Comment: That code seems like you're giving weights to verticies, not edges between verticies. I was thinking this: http://pastebin.com/m1f8ca859 which is a much simpler change to your code. That way each edge has it's own weight. I just set all the weights to 1 in that example, you would probably want to get them from the input file.